# Want to Email a Certain Details while also attaching images from a certain Directory

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a workbook where i want to create a Email Button. Which not only mail the contents of the workbook but also attach a certain directory to the Email as Attachments.

The directory is automatically created by a batch file with the following Coding.

```
mkdir %date:~-4,4%"-"%date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~-7,2%
```

This Create Folders with the name of current Date.
[This is How the Folder Structure Looks like when it is created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO1l1.jpg)

I researched a lot and created a code to send my context of the EXCEL File directly through a click of a button. But was not able to make code work for attachments as well.

The Following Code is used to Send my Mail.

```
Sub EmailRange()
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Excalibur Mail"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "This is an automated Email. Please do not respond"
    .Item.To = "" 'Senders Email ID
    .Item.Subject = "Daily Counts"
    .Item.Send
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The Code Works fine and ask me for Range Selection and does send email to that specific Client. What i need now is to be able to attach all the images that are in the folder which displays the Current Date.

For Eg. if todays date is 26/03/2018. It will Create a folder named 2018-03-26. I need some help in sending my content as well as all the images that are in the current date folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a "aaa.txt" & "bbb.txt" in the new folder for testing. You can check this link on how to add all items in a file as attachment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27319804/Excel-VBA-Attach-All-Files-in-a-Directory.html

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim tdy As String
tdy = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Dim filePath As String
filePath = "YouPath\" & tdy & "\"

Dim strFileName As String

strFileName = Dir(filePath & "*.*")

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "This is an automated Email. Please do not respond"
    .Item.To = "" 'Any mail Id You need
    .Item.Subject = "Daily Counts"
    .Item.Display
    If FolderExists(filePath) Then
        Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
            .Item.attachments.Add filePath & strFileName
            strFileName = Dir
        Loop
        Else
            MsgBox "Folder " & tdy & " not Found!"
    End If
End With

End Sub

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

    FolderExists = False
    Dim objFSO As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True
End Function
```

Comment: I actually don't want to create a folder. Instead i want it to find the folder which have today's date and then attach all the .jpeg images which are inside that folder. I tried this but it is not working exactly the way i wanted it to be. Do i have to setup something for this to work.

Comment: Well, I was following this statement **if todays date is 26/03/2018. It will Create a folder named 2018-03-26. I need some help in sending my content as well as all the images that are in the current date folder.**

Comment: I already update the codes, modify the `filePath` to your path.

Comment: This is working great. Is there any way to send it as a chain email from previous same subject mails

Comment: Edited version available on the internet